# A reg is not a legal lvalue in this context [6.1.2(IEEE)]

Tags: verilog

I do `ncverilog` with two file,`sell.v` and `selltest.v` and its log file says:

```
`ncelab: *E,RANOTL (./selltest.v,6|36): A reg is not a legal lvalue in this context [6.1.2(IEEE)].
vendor vendor(NT5,NT10,clk,reset,cola,change);


ncelab: *E,RANOTL (./selltest.v,6|43): A reg is not a legal lvalue in this context [6.1.2(IEEE)].
ncverilog: *E,ELBERR: Error during elaboration (status 1), exiting.`
```

Only my `selltest.v` has `"vendor vendor(NT5,NT10,clk,reset,cola,change);"`,and i don't know what's going on,part of my program is as below

```
`timescale 1ns/1ns

module test_vendor;

reg NT5 , NT10 , clk , reset;

//wire cola , change;
reg cola , change;

vendor vendor(NT5,NT10,clk,reset,cola,change);
```

Comment: See http://go.mentor.com/wire-vs-reg

Comment: actually,i wrote `wire cola , change;` first,but the log file says ''A net is not a legal lvalue in this [9.3.1(IEEE)].so i write `reg cola , change;` to improve this problem

Answer (score 2):

You're trying to connect a module output to a `reg`. You can't do that: you have to drive a net (ie. `wire`/etc). See 12.3.9 in the 2005 LRM for port connection rules:

> Only nets or structural net expressions shall be the sinks in an
>   assignment

This all got cleaned up in SystemVerilog, where the distinction between regs and wires was corrected/clarified.

An 'lvalue' is something which can appear on the left-hand side of an assignment (Left Value), ie it can be assigned to, and so is a 'sink'.